# How can I reserve all values of an enum in proto3?

Tags: proto3

I have a field of an enum type that I would like to deprecate. No clients use this field or its enum type. I want to reserve all of the values in this enum so that it cannot be reused.

```
message Example {
    ...
    enum Foo {
        BAR = 0;
        BAZ = 1;
    }
    Foo foo = 42;
}
```

My first thought was to try reserving the values from `0 to max` as follows:

```
message Example {
    ...
    enum Foo {
        reserved "BAR", "BAZ";
        reserved 0 to max;
    }
    reserved "foo";
    reserved 42;
}
```

However, I get an error stating that `Foo` must contain at least one value. Is there any way to deprecate an entire enum like this in order to make sure it isn't reused?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't reserve an entire enum (as far as I know since a zero value is required), you *can* reserve anything that ever was in it, and every use of it.

```
message Example {
    ...
    enum Foo {
        reserved "BAR", "BAZ";
        reserved 1 to max;
        RESERVED = 0;
    }
    reserved "foo";
    reserved 42;
}
```